# Get error "Unable to determine constructor argument #1: missing parameter of type Factory.... " trying to build Android-SimpleLocation

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When trying to build [Android-SimpleLocation](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-SimpleLocation), I get the following error:

```
Unable to determine constructor argument #1: missing parameter of type Factory, or no service of type Factory<LoggingManagerInternal>.
Open File (which is a link to my build.gradle file)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

You're using following dependencies,

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
```

Update these with following or higher.

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing this line `org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true` from `gradle.properties` solved my problem